# Changing orientation removes UI elements

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, android-scrollview

When the phone is in portrait mode, it shows the title and image at the top and below that there's the button and `ListView` with comments. However when I turn the phone to be in landscape mode, the button and `ListView` dissapear and only the title and image are shown. I basically can't scroll below the image anymore.

There is a third element -- a `TextView` for the body -- that is also inside that `ScrollView`: each layout will either have that `TextView` with content or an image. The same thing happens when it's the `TextView` that has content and no image. This does not occur when the image or text *don't* take up the entire screen though.

Portrait mode:

[image]

Landscape mode:

[image]

Accompanying code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="net.vannevel.redditapp.activities.PostActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/postDetailTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/postDetailImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/postDetailBody"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/postDetailViewOnlineButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onViewOnlineButtonClicked"
        android:text="View original source" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="COMMENTS" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/postDetailCommentList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your problem is that the items you have inside the scroll view are taller than the screen height in landscape. Even if you scroll inside the `ScrollView`, there's nothing you can do once you get to the end of it. All the elements placed outside the `ScrollView` are going to be off screen and placed outside any scrollable container.

I can see 3 possible solutions:

1 - set fixed size to the scroll view so that it doesn't occupy the whole screen, so that you let the other views in. Not practical, however: phone in landscape means short height and you have to fit a picture and list with comments...

2 - have a different layout for landscape - picture on left, list with comments on right

3 - get rid of the `ScrollView` and set everything above the `ListView` as a `ListView` header (`addHeaderView`)
For example:

Step 1 - extract everything you have on top of the `ListView` and put it into a different layout file - let's call it `header.xml`

Step 2 - inflate the layout:

```
View headerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, listView, false);
```

Step 3 - initialize the items on the header just like you do it now

Step 4 - set the view as the header of the list `ListView`:

```
listView.addHeaderView(headerView, null, false);
```

The side effect of this approach is that the header, being part of the `ListView` now, it will scroll as you scroll the list. Also, it will offset your position in the adapter by 1.

Comment: I guess a separate layout might in fact make the most sense then. However even in portrait mode: when for example the text is too big for the screen, it will be placed in a scrollview which in turn removes the other items (comments) from the screen. I can't fix this with a different layout since it's already portrait mode. What is the advised approach then?

Comment: I would either go with choice#3 or show comments into a different screen. I will update the answer shortly with more details about choice#3

Comment: Alright, cheers. That gives me enough to work with. I appreciate the explanation you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
   <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
```

Or implemet two `layouts` `portland` and `landscape` orientation.

Comment: That doesn't make a difference (500dp or anything else). I'm not sure how creating a different layout file would make a difference given that it would be the same layout as now.

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: I did, but you put it on the wrong control: it's the `ScrollView` that needs the `layout_height` set to `300dp`. This feels a little hacky though but I'll keep it in mind.